# Popup Image is not getting opened on More Info link using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to open a popup window of an Image on More Info link but I am not getting any popup image on that.. This is the code for More Info link.

```
 <a href="#?w=700" rel="popup2" class="poplight">
                    <div class="meta">
                    <div class="show-more-info">+ More Info</div>
                    </div>
                    </a>
```

**And this is jquery part.**

```
<script>

var id_popover_content = '#popover_content';
var id_popover = '#popover';
var id_popover_mask = '#popover-mask';

var template_popover_waiting    = '<div class="waiting"></div>';

var current_doc_info = {id:'', url:'', title:'', repo:'', app:'docsearch2', ts:'', user:''};

var template_popover = '<div id="popover" class="popover"><div class="content clearfix"><div class="t"></div><div id="popover_content"></div></div><div class="b"><div></div></div></div>';
var template_meta = '<p class="item"><span class="label">{label}</span><span class="data">{data}</span></p>';



var template_popover= '<div id="popup-meta"><h4>Meta Data</h4><div class="popup-content"><div class="waiting">Getting meta data&#8230;</div></div></div><div id="popup-revisions"><h4>Revision Info</h4><div class="popup-content"><div class="waiting">Getting revisions info&#8230;</div></div></div><div id="popup-where"><h4>Where Used Info</h4><div class="popup-content"><div class="waiting">Getting where used info&#8230;</div></div></div>';


        $('body').append($('<div id="popover-mask"></div>'));

        $(id_popover_mask).click(on_popover_close);

        $('body').append($(template_popover));
        
                
    
        
$('.show-more-info').live('click', function(e) {

        alert("helo");
        e.preventDefault();

        //$(this).addClass('active');

        show_popover_mask();
        
        // Position the popover
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var left = offset.left - 442;
        var top = offset.top + 5;
        left = left + 'px';
        top = top + 'px';
        $(id_popover).stop(true, false).show().css({left: left,top: top}).attr('class', 'popover popover-show-info');
        
        // Get service class
        //current_doc_info.id = $('a', $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent()).html();
        
         current_doc_info.id = $('a', $(this).parent().parent().parent()).html();
        
        var id1 = $('a', $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()).html();
        
        //alert("heloo: " +id);
        //alert("helooss: " +id1);
        //alert($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().html());
        
        
        $(id_popover_content).css({width:'500px'}).html(template_popover);
                on_show_info();
    });

var show_popover_mask = function() {
alert("a1");
        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();
        alert(maskHeight);

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $(id_popover_mask).css({
                'width': maskWidth,
                'height': maskHeight
        });

        //transition effect
        $(id_popover_mask).show().css({
                opacity: '0.33'
        });
    };
        
        
        var on_popover_close = function(e) {

        //e.preventDefault();
        $(id_popover_mask).hide();
        
        $(id_popover).hide();

        
        
        $('.show-more-info').removeClass('active');
    };

var on_show_info= function() {
                alert("aa");
                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: search_metadata + current_doc_info.id,
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                            dataType: "xml",
                success: on_get_metadata,
                error: on_get_metadata_error

        });
        


    };


    var on_get_metadata= function(data, text_status, XMLHttpRequest) {

        alert(data);
        var html = '';
        var info = {};

        $(data).find('str').each(function() {

                info = {};
                info.data = $(this).attr('value');

                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                alert(name);

                switch (name) {
                case "TitleBlock.Number":
                    info.label = 'Item Number';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.Description":
                    info.label = 'Description';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.DocumentType":
                    info.label = 'Item Type';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.rev":
                    info.label = 'Item Rev';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.Category":
                    info.label = 'Category';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.ProductLine":
                    info.label = "Product Line";
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.RevReleaseDate":
                    info.label = 'Modified Date';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                case "TitleBlock.RevIncorpDate":
                    info.label = 'Incorporated Date';
                    html += $.nano(template_meta, info);
                    break;
                }
        });

        $('#popup-meta').removeClass('waiting');
        $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html(html);
    };

    var on_get_metadata_error = function(XMLHttpRequest, text_status, error) {
        //log('on_get_metadata_error: ' + text_status);
        alert("error");
        $('#popup-meta').removeClass('waiting');
        $('#popup-meta .popup-content').html('<span class="data-error">Unable to get meta data.</span>');
    };


      

</script>
```

---

**This is the CSS.**

/*------------------POPUPS------------------------*/

```
#popover-mask {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:999;
  background-color:#FFF;
  display:none;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popover {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    color: #2a2a2a;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}

.popover .content, .popover .t, .popover .b, .popover .b div {
    background:transparent url('../kit/light/images/popover.png') no-repeat top right;
}

.popover .content {
    position:relative;
    zoom:1;
    _overflow-y:hidden;
    padding:32px 16px 0 0;
}

.popover .t {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:16px;
    margin-left:-16px;
    height:100%;
    _height:1600px;
    background-position:top left;
}

.popover .b {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

.popover .b,.popover .b div {
    height:16px;
    font-size:1px;
}

.popover .b {
    background-position:bottom right;
}

.popover .b div {
    position:relative;
    width:16px;
    margin-left:-16px;
    background-position:bottom left;
}

.search-results .show-more-info.active,.search-results .show-actions.active,.search-results .show-user.active { filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#53b5e7',endColorStr='#43a2d2'); }

/* CLEAR FIX*/
.clearfix:after {
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden;
}

.clearfix {
    display:inline-block;
}


    
/* Hides from IE-mac \*/
* html .clearfix {
    height:1%;
}

.clearfix {
    display:block;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping your javascript code with $(function(){...}); so that it loads only when the DOM is ready?

Comment: thanks for the information, now it is working fine by adding that.. but If I want to remove that popup window by clicking anywhere on the page.. then that window is not getting removed. It stays on the page... Any idea why is it happening??

Comment: try putting the `declarations` (i.e. `var ____ =""`, or `function ____ (){}`) stuff outside of the `$(function(){....});` but leaving all the stuff like `$('.show-more-info').live('click', function(e) {......});` inside of the `$(function(){...});`

Comment: to be more specific, I think if you put `var on_popover_close = function(e){...};` outside of the `$(function(){...});` then that specific function should work